# get sensor value each n seconds

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to get a sensor's value each n seconds.
Setting time in register listener does not seem to be enough as if no changes occur no event will be called, while I want to get sensor's value even if it did not change...

Comment: Which sensor?  In general, it doesn't make sense for a sensor to report it's value if it hasn't changed since the last report in order to reduce CPU and therefore battery usage.

Why can't you remember the value and, if you don't receive a report, use the previously remembered value?

Comment: Accellerometer...however your suggestion is right, but I don't know how to set frequency rate. Say I want an update every n seconds: if I set it just to n seconds I could miss the event when I go reading. On the other hand, if I set it to less than n and an event takes place (acceleration >0), than accelaration stops (acceleration=0), my variables would contain zero: no movement and this would be a fake.

Comment: You can't control the frequency but, you can receive an event when it changes and, you can read the current value statically and store it statically.  Therefore, when you start, get the value then start your timer.  The important concept is that your timer is only how often you want to update something, NOT how often you read the sensor.  Register a SensorEventListener, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html, to update the statically stored value.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Thread where you can let it sleep for n seconds and then listen for sensor data. You could also create a method in it called something like `getSensorData()` that will return the data type.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem those few days. I solved it in following ways:

In onSensorChanged method, I fist store all data into an array, say it acc[time, acc_x, acc_y, acc_z]. 
Every time there's a sensor change, I will check the difference between this timestamp and the first timestamp stored in the acc, which is acc[0]. If the difference is larger than 0.2s(use the timespan you want), I will use the average of acc, say meanAcc, in the timespan, and store it into another array.
Then the acc will be cleared. And repeat the above steps.

Help this can help.